# Firebase query retrieves data in a random order. The data is organised by autoID

Tags: swift, firebase

I've got the following database structure:

PVV
 -- AutoID
      - Data1
      - Data2
      - Status: Active
      - ImageName: Path\FirebaseStorageImage.jpg

I'd like to retrieve the data in chronological order, and then sort the data in a descending manner (most recent first).

I think autoID does use a combination of date and time, and Firebase does normally retrieve the data in a fixed order.  I am using the same function as below to retrieve text data (that does not have an imageName), and that works fine.

However, the function below returns data in a random order:

```
    func LoadDataFromImageTest() {
    self.ImageList.removeAll()
    self.ImageTestFromFBTableView.reloadData()

    databaseReference = Database.database().reference()

    let refPVV = Database.database().reference(withPath: "PVV").queryOrdered(byChild: "Status").queryEqual(toValue: "Active")

    refPVV.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { [weak self] (snapshot) in

        //if the reference have some values
        if snapshot.childrenCount > 0 {

            //clearing the list
            self?.ImageList.removeAll()

            //iterating through all the values
            for PVV in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot] {
                //getting values
                let PVVObject = PVV.value as? [String: AnyObject]
                // let PVVText  = PVVObject?["ImageString"]

                let PVVName = PVVObject?["Name"]
                let PVVBodyText = PVVObject?["BodyText"]
                let PVVValue = PVVObject?["PVVValue"]
                let Key = PVV.key
                let PVVImageName = PVVObject?["ImageName"] as! String?

   let imageURL = Storage.storage().reference().child(PVVImageName!)

                imageURL.downloadURL(completion: { (url, error) in

                    if error != nil {
                        print(error?.localizedDescription as Any)
                        return
                    }

                    PVVurlName = url
                let PVV = ImageModel(Name: PVVName as!String?, BodyText: PVVBodyText as! String?, PVVValue: PVVValue as! String?, Key: Key as String?, ImageName: PVVurlName as URL?)
                    self!.ImageList.insert(PVV, at: 0)
                    self?.ImageTestFromFBTableView.reloadData()
                })
            }
        }
        }
    )}
```

I set a debug point right before I start downloading the URL.  Each time I run, it returns values for PVVObject in a different order.

I have another tree like this:

Challenges
     - AutoID
       - Data1
       - Data 2
       - Status: Active

I've recycled the function above to retrieve data from the above tree, and I always get the data in the same order, when setting a debug point in the same place.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I just tried building a new view controller that simply grabs the imageName and dumps them into the tableviewcells.  It doesn't translate the image names into URLs.  This works perfectly, and the order of sorting is correct.

This means that things get out of order when the URLs are being generated.  How do I solve this?

Comment: Some further tests.  Firebase is loading data into the snapshot in the correct order, and is always consistent.  However, the URLs are getting generated in a random order before being put into the model.  

How do I keep the URL generation in sync?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasestorage/api/reference/Classes/StorageReference#/c:objc(cs)FIRStorageReference(im)downloadURLWithCompletion:) the downloadURL method is asynchronous. It means that the order in which the downloaded files are retrieved is not guaranteed. When you are in the completion block of the downloadURL method, you have no idea to which PPV object the image belongs to.

I think the best is to change the architecture of your code. Create an object model class for PPV, with a imageUrl property (which is attached to each instance), and trigger the download job when you observe a change in value of this property (in the didSet method for instance). This way you will be sure that the downloaded file belongs to the instance.

Comment: Alternatively, I suppose I can get the URL when I initially upload the image, and store that in Firebase.  Then, when time to load the image in a tableview, I can pull the URL as a string and pass to SDWebImage.

Comment: As long as you do not attempt to download the image in the observeSingleEvent block in the datasnapshot loop it would be ok I suppose.

Comment: Good point.  I was planning on putting the url into the model, which is then used in the tableview... where I would retrieve the url, and use it with SDWebImage.   Now if only I can figure out how to get the download url working after uploading the image.  I have another thread on this, but it’s yet to receive any answers.